# How to set the webhook parameter for a connector card in Teams

Tags: c#, microsoft-teams

I made a nice working webhook for a Teams channel and I would like to use the parameter "assigned to" but I do not really understand how to do this and can't find it.

this is my connector card:

```
{
    '@type': 'MessageCard',
    '@context': 'http://schema.org/extensions',
    'themeColor': 'FF0000',
    'summary': '" + item.Name + @"',
    'sections': [{
        'activityTitle': 'Die Aufgabe " + item.Name + @" wurde aktualisiert',
        'activitySubtitle': ' " + item.AnzahlNeu + @" neue Artikel zugewiesen [+" + item.Wachstum.ToString().Substring(0, 5) + @"%]',
        'activityImage': 'pic',
        'facts': [{
            'name': 'Assigned to',
            'value': '???'
            }, {
            'name': 'Due date',
            'value': '" + DateTime.Now.AddDays(1).ToString("HH:mm:ss dd.MM.yyyy") + @"'
            }, {
            'name': 'Status',
            'value': 'Not started'
            }],
            'markdown': true
        }]
}
```

How can I add the assigned to property that it matches up with the teams user, or is my approach incorrect?

I am trying to @mention a user in webhook

Comment: Are you trying to @mention a user in webhook? Could you please share more context of what you are trying to do?

Comment: This is what I want to achieve

Comment: https://amdesigner.azurewebsites.net/ i hope this works, not as sexy, but value lists should work too - will try and update

Answer (score 1):

@mentions in Webhook are currently not supported. The only way to do @mention is by using a Bot. This is currently in the backlog but we do not have a firm ETA to share with you.